# Creating a folder with PHP using input values

Tags: directory, image-uploading, uploading

I am trying to create a folder in PHP, by calling a value. Creating one works fine. But once I try calling the value instead and concatenating it with the existing folder, it won't work. I have tried several things.

For example, I want to be able to have someone type in a name for their folder in an input field, so that they may choose what will the name of the folder be. For example, they could write on the website "mypics", and when I access my ftp program, I would now see images/mypics/

As for the HTML portion, I have this (check the fiddle for the rest of it http://jsfiddle.net/GF6qk/ ):

```
<input type="text" id="folder" name="folder">
```

As for the PHP aspect, I have the following

```
<?php

// We're putting all our files in a directory called images.

// Desired folder structure


$folder = $_POST['folder'];

$dirPath = 'images/'.$folder;
$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);
if ($result == 1) {
    echo $dirPath . " has been created";
} else {
    echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}


//$image_name = '';
$uploaddir = 'images';

// The posted data, for reference
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

// Get the mime
$getMime = explode('.', $name);
$mime = end($getMime);

// Separate out the data
$data = explode(',', $file);

// Encode it correctly
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);


?>
```

I have also used this line (which was the original line I tried in the above code, which I then changed).

```
$dirPath = 'images/$folder';
```

Comment: Do you want to create recursive folders? i.e. if user types **`trip/fun/mypics`** it should create **`images/trip/fun/mypics`**

Comment: Yogesh, not at all. I'll prevent everything except letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and it is working

```
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$dirPath = 'images/'.$folder;
$result = mkdir($dirPath);

if ($result == '1') {

echo $dirPath . " has been created";

} else {
echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}

<input type="text"  id="folder" name="folder">
```

Comment: I did something else which worked months ago. And this code seems good to me as well :)

Comment: here the same code i have been created with dynamically create folder and upload file process
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817829/files-not-being-uploaded-in-dynamically-created-folders-subfolders/19817946?noredirect=1#comment29466299_19817946

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any errors? If so, what are they? Does the "images" folder already exist? I tried your exact code, and it worked if the images folder already exists.....

Comment: No error whatsoever - not even the PHP error!

Yes, if I create a form in the style that you tried, it works. But, the problem I have is more complicated :/ I will show you the html code I have which leads me to ponder how I can create a directory for this particular problem. 

Users will be dragging and dropping their pics on the site, and I'll want them to choose a name for their directory simultaneously (well, almost simultaneously).

http://jsfiddle.net/GF6qk/

Comment: here the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817829/files-not-being-uploaded-in-dynamically-created-folders-subfolders/19817946?noredirect=1#comment29466299_19817946