# Files not being uploaded in dynamically created folders/subfolders

Tags: php, forms, mkdir, uploading

i need help to solve this problem Files not being uploaded in dynamically created folders/subfolders!

creating a dynamically `subfolder` using `input type text` and when i uploaded file moved to `uploads folders` but not moved to `subfolder` which is create using `input type text?`

but dynamically creating function working fine and also showing me folder which is typed in the textbox into the upload folder

**Here My Code**

```
//creating dynamically subfolders 
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
foreach( $folder as $key => $value){
$dirPath = 'uploads/'.$value;
$result = mkdir($dirPath);
}

if ($result == '1') {

//file move on function
$target_path = 'uploads/'.$results;
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";

} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
} else {
echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
}
}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="text"  id="folder" name="folder"><br />
<input type="submit" name="test" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**My Problem Is Solved Now I Have Completed My Script**

```
//creating a folder 
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$dirPath = 'uploads/'.$folder;
$result = mkdir($dirPath);

if ($result == '1') {

//file move on        
$target_path = $dirPath .'/' . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
     echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";

  } else{
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
  }

 } else {
   echo $dirPath . " has NOT been created";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Replace

```
 $target_path = 'uploads/'.$results;
```

into

```
$target_path = $dirPath.'/';
```

Otherwise,

```
$target_path = $dirPath .'/'. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
}
```

Comment: is this something like this `$target_path = /$dirPath/. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);` bcz of when i `echo $target_path`  it is showing me folder name which is created by textbox

`uploads/test1236203_10153283876195472_1932123741_n.jpg`

Comment: yes thanks i solved it and updated my question with solution may be it  will work for others :)

Comment: chinnu r can you solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822999/create-dynamically-multiple-subdirectory-into-folder-using-multiple-input-type-t thanks in advanced?

Comment: Added solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Where is $results defined?  You are using it here:

`$target_path = 'uploads/'.$results;`

Why?

Also, $result is the true or false return of mkdir() so you can't use that one either.