# Create dynamically multiple subdirectory into folder using multiple input type textboxes in For Loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, mkdir

i need help to solve how to create dynamically multiple folders using `input type textbox`?
i can create only single dynamically subdirectory into the folder but i want to multiple subfolder when multiple input type textbox are display?

problem is that i can create only one subdirectory into the folder at time using input type textboxes

i have already create multiple textbox using javascript?

**Php Code**

```
//creating a folder 
$folder = implode($_POST['folder']);

for($i=0; $i<$folder; $i++)
{

$dirPath = 'uploads/'.$folder.[$i];
$result = mkdir($dirPath);

}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;

function changeIt(){
i++;

var table=document.getElementById("itemdetail");

var row=table.insertRow();

var cell1=row.insertCell();

cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='folder[]' id=folder_"+i+"'/>";

}

</script>
```

**Form**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text"  name="folder[]" id="folder_0" /><br />

//dynamically creating textbox into table row 
<table id="itemdetail"></table>

<input type="button" n="addnewitem" id="addnewitem"  
value="Add New Question" onClick="changeIt()"/>

</form>
```

**For Example**

```
input type value is test1 ... uploads/subdirectory = test1
input type value is test2 ... uploads/subdirectory = test2
input type value is test3 ... uploads/subdirectory = test3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
            if(isset($_POST)){

                    $folders = $_POST['folder'];

                    foreach($folders as $folder){
                            $dirPath = 'uploads/'.$folder;
                            $result = mkdir($dirPath);
                    }
            }
```

Comment: chinnu r is this script is completed i have created like this?
`//creating a folder 
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
foreach( $folder as $key => $value){
$dirPath = 'uploads/'.$value;
$result = mkdir($dirPath);
}`

Comment: chinnu r i need one more help from your side actually i have created multiple subdirectories into the main folder but i want to upload multiple images according to the subdirectories which are created into the main folder i have pasted my code here pls if you solve this issue also http://pastebin.com/30XnWqcK in this script it is showing this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 11`
thanks you helped me alot